# How to insert schedule with date and time in Emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, format, org-mode, schedule

When I insert a schedule with <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> in Emacs `org-mode`, it always inserts a date like this:

```
* TODO write product documents
  SCHEDULED: <2013-10-25 Fri>
```

while what I want is this:

```
* TODO write product documents
  SCHEDULED: <2013-10-25 Fri 11:34>
```

Now I do this manually: firstly insert a schedule, then delete the date, then insert a timestamp with date and time using <kbd>C-u C-c .</kbd>.

How can I insert a schedule with date *and* time only using <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd>?

Thanks.

Comment: Function `org-schedule` doesn't support time substring in `time-stamp`, date only. You want `org-mode` automatically inserts time value, but which by default?

Comment: @artscan, I don't know which function can insert time string. I think the most convenient way is the best.

Comment: What does `11:34` mean in your example? You schedule time in a future. If I use `C-u C-c .` it inserts current time. Do you want `C-c C-s` inserts current time for schedule too?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When you're being asked for a date at the prompt, you can also enter a time.
e.g. if I say "+2d 1pm" at the prompt, I get

`SCHEDULED: <2013-10-25 ven. 13:00>`

in the buffer. See [Info page](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-date_002ftime-prompt.html) `(info "(org) The date/time prompt")` for more info about the prompt.