# org-mode: org-time-stamp-custom-formats shows midnight time

Tags: emacs, customization, org-mode

I want to have timestamps for my TODOs in the following format:

`<%d/%m/%Y %a [%H:%M]>`

In my `.emacs` I have the following:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-display-custom-times t)
 '(org-time-stamp-custom-formats (quote ("<%d/%m/%Y %a [%H:%M]>" . "<%d %m %Y  %a [%H:%M]>"))))
```

Checking the value of that variable via

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-time-stamp-custom-formats`

shows:

```
org-time-stamp-custom-formats is a variable defined in `org.el'.
Its value is ("<%d/%m/%Y %a [%H:%M]>" . "<%d %m %Y  %a [%H:%M]>")

Documentation:
Custom formats for time stamps.  See `format-time-string' for the syntax.
These are overlaid over the default ISO format if the variable
`org-display-custom-times' is set.  Time like %H:%M should be at the
end of the second format.  The custom formats are also honored by export
commands, if custom time display is turned on at the time of export.

You can customize this variable.
```

However, when going in action (by pressing <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd>) I get always my TODOs scheduled at `00:00`:

```
** TODO SCHEDULED: <22/04/2014 Tue [00:00]>
```

Something is going wrong in my config I suppose. How can I correct my configuration of timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to make it work

1. Remove the `[%H:%M]` portion from the first element of `org-time-stamp-custom-formats`. The relevant parts of your config file should look like this:

   ```
   (custom-set-variables
    ;; ...
    '(org-time-stamp-custom-formats (quote ("<%d/%m/%Y %a>" . "<%d %m %Y  %a [%H:%M]>"))))
   ```
2. To schedule an item,

   - hit <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> (as usual)
   - enter a time, e.g. `1pm`, `10am`, `9:00`, or `18:00`
   - hit <kbd>RET</kbd>

#### Explanation

As far as I can tell from skimming documentation and associated portions of the `org-mode` source, `org-mode` uses the first element of

```
("<%d/%m/%Y %a [%H:%M]>" . "<%d %m %Y  %a [%H:%M]>")
```

for formatting dates that do *not* include a time, while the second element is used for formatting dates that do. So when you do <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> immediately followed by <kbd>RET</kbd> **without providing a time**, `org-mode` will try to insert a  date formatted according to the *first* element of `org-time-stamp-custom-formats`. With your current configuration this will fail (in the way you describe) because `org-mode` doesn't know what to substitute for `%H` and `%M` in the format string.

The thing that had me confused (and probably tripped you up as well) when I tried to reproduce the behavior you describe was that the date prompt that comes up when calling `org-schedule` via <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> *does* include the (current) time in the correct format...

#### Credits

- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19538085/1199226) to a similar question about timestamps for scheduled TODOs.

Comment: Thanks for the solution 2. and the explanation. The funny point, that you mentioned confused me too. You see the time correctly displayed, but not used in the final time stamp. But Ok, the solution you gave is just fine for my needs.